# How can I field-rewrite a URL?

Tags: views, uri

I need the modified URL to call a view with contextual filter, in Drupal 8.
The URL must include the value of a field, that the user's clicking on.

This works.

```
<a href="{{ url('view.testview.page_1', {'arg_0': field_example__value}) }}">Link to Testview</a>
```

How can I overwrite *Link to Testview* with the field value?

`{{field_example__value}}` works as well.

Comment: Sorry, if I express myself unclear I'm beginner... 4*4k helped me a bit further.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it often that the path is simply built by concatenating strings. But if you want to do it in a D8 way, then use the route from the view.

You can investigate the routes with [Drupal Console](https://drupalconsole.com/) on the command line or the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) in UI, where you'll find the routes in */devel/routes*.

For example this view:

```
ROUTE NAME: view.testview.page_1    PATH: /testview/{arg_0}/{arg_1}
```

When you know the route name and the arguments for the contextual filters you can build the URL:

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

  $url = Url::fromRoute('view.testview.page_1', [
    'arg_0' => $arg1,
    'arg_1' => $arg2,
  ]);
```

The URL is an object, which you put in a render array, for example in a link element. If needed you can get the path as string with the method `->toString()`, but this should be avoided.

If you want to use the route in a field rewrite you can use the twig function `url()` in a field replacement pattern:

```
<a href="{{ url('view.testview.page_1', {'arg_0': field_example__value}) }}">Link to Testview</a>
```

Comment: No, I meant something different. The view returns a field, token says: [node: field_betreuer]. How do I get the content of this field appending to the URL? "%" or "$" does not seem to work. It must be easy to transfer the contents of this field to the URL, isn't it?
How to write this?

Comment: @FrankGiesecke, added an example for a field rewrite. Please provide more details what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, that works. How can I overwrite "Link to Testview" with field value? - field_example__value itself doesn't work.

Comment: {{field_example__value}} works as well. Thx